# Is Headon involved with FUG?

Tags: tower-of-god

As we know from season one of Tower of God, Headon suggested help to Rachel in exchange for some sort of her help. After this, Rachel ended up being helped by FUG, e.g. having Hwa Ryun as Guide, and receiving help from Yu Han Sung. This also later leads to situation, when FUG forcibly recruits Baam.

So, does all of this mean, that Headon cooperates with FUG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Bam's test, headon asks Rachel that if she fulfills his request then he will allow Rachel to move to the next floor. What was headon's request to rachel is not known till now. [As per wiki](http://towerofgod.wikia.com/wiki/Headon) headon did conspire with Yu Han Sung so that Rachel can move up the tower. However, it is unknown if headon conspired with Yu Han Sung out of his own interest or because of his request or about any other reason. Further it is unknown whether headon knows that Yu Han Sung is part of FUG or not.